# WebSocket error 302, after composer update

Tags: websocket, wss, ratchet

Ratchet worked perfect until I updated my composer, after that it produce this error on chrome 
**WebSocket connection to 'wss://mysite.com/wss2/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302**

on Mozilla 
**Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://mysite.com/wss2/.**

httpd.conf

```
ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://myIP:8888/
```

socket.js

```
var conn = new ab.Session('wss://mysite.com/wss2/',
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem? thanks!

Comment: 302 is an http redirect... It means that for some reason rather than starting the websocket something is returning a redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your time Sam,
What can possibly return that redirect? Since it worked before composer update..

Comment: No idea, which is why I left a comment not an answer.  I'm not familiar with some of the technologies you're using, although moderately familiar with websockets and HTTP

Comment: Is 8888 your secure port? You're using ws**s**, meaning you need to reach a secure point (443 as standard port). I guess that the server tells the client to redirect to a secure point. It's like switching from *http* to *https* Could you post the request and response headers?